# After using AirDrop to get a photo from iPhone to Macbook, the file format is HEIC and can I choose "one of" the sequences of photos?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, heic

The HEIC format (and file extension such as `IMG_1201.HEIC`) is probably what the format is when the iPhone takes the photo that is "live" -- that a user can choose one frame out of the many frames for a duration of something like 0.5 seconds.

If viewed on iPhone I can choose one of the split second photo -- such as if somebody blinked the eye, I can choose another one that is 0.2 seconds later right on iPhone.  After "AirDrop" to Macbook Pro (using OS X Mojave), can the default Preview app let the user choose the 0.2 seconds one as on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in Preview.

To make edits to a Live Photo, or to even view the 'live' part of the photo, you need to use a different application.  On the Mac, you can use Photos to view and edit live photos.

Comment: can you add how Photos can do that?  I also tried Photos and "Import" that HEIC file, and I see the photo but didn't see a way to "choose" one frame

Comment: I don't have Mojave but if I remember correctly after you import the pic into Photos you have to click the Edit button. From there you should see at the bottom of the screen the same row of pictures (just like in iOS).  You can select a different image there.

Answer (score 0):

The "live" portion of the video is actually a movie file and the "photo" portion is the selected frame of the video, saved as a HEIF/JPG file.

*As of iOS 16 and macOS Ventura:*

In order to be able to edit the Live Photo on a Mac in the way you are thinking, you must import the photo directly to the Photos app. This can be done via linking your iCloud Library, using Image Capture, or AirDropping a photo. For AirDrop, after hitting the Share button, you must press Options and turn on *All Photos Data* otherwise only the photo portion will be sent.

If you import the photo directly to the Mac filesystem instead of the Photos app, you will get 2 files for the Live Photo - a HEIC and MOV. If you import both those files to the Photos app later, it will recognize it as one Live Photo. Otherwise, you will only be able to open the HEIC in Preview and the MOV in Quicktime.